# Resources to ease transitioning from Bash to Zsh

Tags: zsh

Is there a list where I can search for Zsh functionality that could surprise Bash users or even users with a slightly more ample knowledge of POSIX shells?

I had no luck searching the internet; tried a variety of combinations including the words zsh, pitfalls, idioms, zshism, zsh-ism, zsh for bash users... and others.

Of course, I can always read the documentation, but it would be far more convenient to have a single and easy to search document, something like [GreyCat's BashPitfalls page](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) only for Zsh (just look at that index and the explanations, so pretty).

Other resources and/or tools which could help me transition from Bash to Zsh would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter Stephenson has written two documents for Zsh beginners that are a good place to start:

- [The Zsh reference card](http://www.bash2zsh.com/zsh_refcard/refcard.pdf)
- [A User's Guide to the Z-Shell](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide.html)

Neither of these has been updated since 2003, though.

So, it's a good idea to cross-reference the above with

- [The Z Shell Manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/index.html)

which is updated regularly by Zsh contributors.

Other than that, I've found

- [Moving to zsh](https://scriptingosx.com/2019/06/moving-to-zsh/) by Armin Briegel

a pretty good read, when I was still new to Zsh. Some of it is specific to macOS, but most of it should be useful to anyone moving from Bash to Zsh.